# How to record a video with different background without having a green screen?

Tags: after-effects, premiere, editing, video-recording, greenscreen

I'm wondering if there is a way to change the video background while recording with a different background , It doesn't have to be chosen by me , Just a different background .

Is that's possible?

Answer (score 1):

If it's a static shot, you can try using a difference matte. It doesn't work as well as a chroma key, but it might do the trick. The idea is you'll set up After Effects to key out everythi

Comment: Just remember to use a tripod and get a clean plate before you start filming the action!

Answer (score 0):

If you looking for way to do it in post-prodaction, than you can do it by [rotoscoping](https://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/how-to/rotoscoping.html) in AE. But it depends on what you shooting.

If you specking about "while recording", then just record in different place :)